# Laravel CORS enabled but block only certain requests

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, axios

I'm using Laravel 7 as `REST API` with `CORS` enabled and ReactJS as the frontend.

I can make request to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/login or register` but if i will take info from authenticated user on this url : `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/me` the cors will not be able to handle my request from axios in react.

I have look if i have not missed anything but i don't think so there is my code that i use:

> I'm using JWT for authentification basic route and the basic `AuthController` of it for now.

`AuthController`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new AuthController instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        // I have try to except the me route here but that make nothing.
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login','register']]);
    }

    /**
     * Get a JWT via given credentials.
     *
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function login()
    {
        $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

        if (! $token = auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }

        return $this->respondWithToken($token);
    }

    /**
     * Get the authenticated User.
     *
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function me()
    {
        dd(auth()->user());
        return response()->json(auth()->user());
    }

    /**
     * Log the user out (Invalidate the token).
     *
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        auth()->logout();

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Successfully logged out']);
    }

    /**
     * Refresh a token.
     *
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function refresh()
    {
        return $this->respondWithToken(auth()->refresh());
    }

    /**
     * Get the token array structure.
     *
     * @param  string $token
     *
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    protected function respondWithToken($token)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => auth()->factory('api')->getTTL() * 60
        ]);
    }

    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        $data['password'] = bcrypt($data['password']);
        return User::create($data);
    }
}
```

`CORS Configuration`

```php
<?php

return [

    'paths' => ['api/*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,
];
```

`Profile.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { loadProgressBar } from 'axios-progress-bar'
import 'axios-progress-bar/dist/nprogress.css'
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode'
import axios from 'axios'

export default class Profile extends React.Component {

    state = {
        user: null,
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        loadProgressBar()
        axios.post(axios.defaults.baseURL + 'auth/me')
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res)
            })
            .catch((err) => {console.log(err)})
        // if (localStorage.getItem('token')){
        //     const token = jwtDecode(localStorage.getItem('token'))
        //     console.log(token)
        // }

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Profile Page</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

`My index.js with interceptor and default baseURL for authentification, ...`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import axios from 'axios';

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8000/api/'
if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {
    axios.interceptors.request.use(config => {
        let prefix = '?'
        if (config.url.includes(prefix)) {
            prefix = '&'
        }
        config.url += prefix+'token='+localStorage.getItem('token')
        return config
    })
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it on removing dd function from me function :)

Comment: i think you should close your post because there is not any problem and you have fix it by your own

Comment: just include closed keyword in your tiile, like in the end of your title write [closed]